# Prevent social account creation in allauth

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-allauth

Is it possible to prevent account creation under certain circumstances in allauth, preferably using the pre_social_login signal?

Answer (score 10):

With the current development branch you can easily do this. In your settings:

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'my.adapter.MySocialAccountAdapter'
```

Then use this adapter.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

from allauth.socialaccount.adapter import DefaultSocialAccountAdapter
from allauth.exceptions import ImmediateHttpResponse

class MySocialAccountAdapter(DefaultSocialAccountAdapter):
    def pre_social_login(self, request, sociallogin):
        raise ImmediateHttpResponse(HttpResponse('Closed for the day'))
```

Alternatively, raise a similar exception from your `pre_social_login` signal (although I do not prefer that approach -- see documentation notes over at https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/socialaccount/adapter.py#L15

Comment: But this would change the adapter for all the Social Providers, can I use some setting like ``MY_SOCIAL_ SOCIALACCOUNT_ADAPTER`` for MySocialProvider?

Comment: You can inspect `sociallogin.account.provider`, and selectively raise the exception based on the type of provider.

Comment: It would be cumbersome when I have a lot of providers to deal with distinctly. Configure them separately would be more neat I think.